# call a class method inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

In my component, I have one method in which I am attaching a jquery event binding.

```
jqueryNextDataEditableShow() {
    $('#symbolTable .editable').on('hidden', function (e, reason) {
      if (reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
        var $next = $(this).closest('td').next().find('.editable');
        if($next != undefined && $next.length == 0){
          //call that method
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
          $next.editable('show');
        }, 300);
      }
    });
  }
```

I have another method in the class, `onSimulate()`.

```
onSimulate(){
   console.log("onSimulate Method Called");
}
```

I want to call it inside the `jqueryNextDataEditableShow()` where I put the comment mark. Problem I'm facing is, inside the function `this` keyword will point to the document tag or element.

Comment: use `arrow function` to keep original context.

Comment: Couple of suggestions here: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function `=>` instead like this -

```
jqueryNextDataEditableShow() {
    $('#symbolTable .editable').on('hidden',  (e, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
        var $next = $(this).closest('td').next().find('.editable');
        if($next != undefined && $next.length == 0){
          //call that method
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          $next.editable('show');
        }, 300);
      }
    });
  }
```

For more into `arrow function` read here -

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Then, `$(this).closest('td')` won't work, right?

Comment: Not sure, but this should work IMO

Comment: If you use an arrow function, the `this` will be inherited from the parent scope, so `$(this)` won't work - you'll solve one problem at the expense of creating another. You should select the element explicitly.

Comment: `this will be inherited from the parent scope` Yes you are right, Thank you for pointing it out !! Can you please update my answer with your solution or add new answer

Comment: I'm not sure about the `hidden` event (can't find it in cursory searching), but it might be that `e.target` references the element that gets hidden. `$next = $(e.target).closest(...` might work

Comment: @YashJain can you please try this code